# LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'python38.lib' with CMake finding library

Tags: python, visual-c++, cmake

I'm trying to link a python library to a CMake target and build a module from it (using Boost.Python3). CMake correctly finds Boost.Python3 and Python3, but when linking, I get the error `LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'python38.lib'`

I have added the correct `python38.lib` to my PATH (and LIBPATH), and CMake correctly finds the library:

```
message(STATUS "Python3_LIBRARIES = ${Python3_LIBRARIES}")
```

results in

```
-- Python3_LIBRARIES = optimized;C:/Program Files/Python38/libs/python38.lib;debug;C:/Program Files/Python38/libs/python38_d.lib
```

and I link all the libraries:

```
  target_link_libraries(trgt PRIVATE
          ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
          ${Python3_LIBRARIES}
          Python3::Python # tried with and without this line
          trgtCore)
```

I'm compiling with `$ cmake .. "-GVisual Studio 16 2019" -A x64` which matches my x64 installation of Python 3.8.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem when installing opencv version 4 from github, I solved it by copying the .lib file into the visual studio project.

Hope it helps,
Amar.

Answer (score 1):

The same problem occurs for me only when building Debug configuration. Release cfg is been built without this problem.
Debug cfg was been built normally until I installed debug symbols package. Maybe the problem somewhere in there.

Based on this discussion https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/10649